# Ruby hash encrypting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, activesupport

I trying to encrypt and decrypt hash in Ruby by using `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor`. Firstly I create and serialize hash:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
serialized_hash = Marshal.dump(hash) #=> "\x04\b{\a:\x06ai\x06:\x06bi\a"
```

Then I crypt serialized hash:

```
salt  = SecureRandom.random_bytes(64)
key   = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new('password').generate_key(salt) # => "\x89\xE0\x156\xAC..."
crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(key)
crypted_string = crypt.encrypt_and_sign(serialized_hash)
#=> "NHhLdDMwQS9MMkwwK1RFZjMyOFJNRXRkZ2VJY1o3aGtwaC9Wb0wvSnhmVT0tLW1nWTNqUElPWEdhMCsrMHI5R2FST2c9PQ==--01150a6eae1691887ace4164019fea2bd353f092"
```

Problem is that I can not decrypt it:

```
crypt.decrypt_and_verify(crypted_string)
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:49:in `verify'
```

However, sometimes it works. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your understanding of a **hash** is different from my understanding of **hash**. Is this a ruby thing? Mouse over the *hash* tag to see my understanding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think Ruby calls their hashmap / dict data type ["hash"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Data_types#Hashes).

Comment: require the json library, then just call { foo: :bar }.to_json. Simplifies encryption and will be easy to parse back to a hash on decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, adding this last step gives me the original hash

```
result = crypt.decrypt_and_verify(crypted_string)
Marshal.load(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a different variable name compared to the name you used as the argument in the last command.  The following command works for me:

```
crypt.decrypt_and_verify(crypted_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the same key/salt. If you're trying that in console, the problem is most probably in variable name `encrypted_string` vs `crypted_string = ...`